# How do I make an output like this using Java for-loops?

Tags: java, for-loop, tic-tac-toe

```
1      2      3    
4      5      6   
7      8      9
```

I'm making a tic-tac-toe game with this;-;

I tried a formula but it only turned out as

```
0    0    0
1    1    1
2    2    2
```

Would also really appreciate it if you could also direct me on how to change the numbers to X/O when chosen.

```
int[][] x = new int[3][3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(i+1+j+ "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

I apologize, I'm really quite new to this.

Comment: Your code example should be in the question, not the comments. Please [edit] the question. If you want to output the cell number, you would do `row * 3 + column + 1`. This is basic math. Or you could create a "counter" variable prior to the loops and increment it inside the inner-most loop. You may wish to enclose the entire math expression in parentheses if you intend to also perform string operations on it. Or output the tab character in a separate statement.

Comment: Writing a tic tac toe game is far more involved than printing out the shown matrix.  You may want to focus on some simpler things until your coding skills evolve.  Another thing is to pick a class, say String, and play around with the methods.  Then move to another class.  Then when you want to write a program, you may remember something you learned during that process that would help that you wouldn't have previously known you could do.  I also recommend you check out Oracles java tutorials.

Comment: [The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 for-loops for this. One for-loop to iterate over the rows and the other for loop is to iterate through the columns.

> Refer the working sample [here](https://onlinegdb.com/hW52IMElM)

Refer the code below :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rows = 3;
        int cols = 3;

        for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {
                System.out.print((i - 1) * cols + j + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

```
1      2      3    
4      5      6   
7      8      9
```